# Delete selected row from a JTable as well as the source file

Tags: java, swing, jtable, text-files

I'm pretty new to Java and I need your help. I'm using a JTable to display data from a text file. I created an erase button to delete selected rows from the table. I managed to delete rows from JTable but since it doesn't delete the actual data row from the text file, whenever I update the table, all the data comes back. I wanna delete the selected row from the table as well as from the text file. Since I'm new to Java, any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing :-) Please consider posting a SSCCE that demonstrates what you are doing and how it doesn't meet your expectation

Comment: Thank you for your kind attention :-) but I just solved my problem, now I'm able to delete the selected row from the table as well as the source txt file. But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: glad you found it - you might consider posting an answer explaining what went wrong and how you solved it, thus the question will be helpful to others as well :-)